# update the sqlite_sequence table in java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite JDBC in java and  I generate an SQLite table (in java), I want to give a custom value for AUTOINCREMENT to start like 4521 but I don't know how to do it in java I know I have to change `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table but  I don't know how to do it in java.
this is my code in java :) PLEASE help me Thanks.

```
private static void hasDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Connection myConn = null;
    Statement myStmt = null;
    Statement mystmtTwo = null;


    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mylibrary.db");

    myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

    myStmt.execute("CREATE TABLE mymembers ( idmymembers    INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,"
            + "membername     VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,"
            + "memberlastname VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,"
            + "memberage      INT (11)     NOT NULL,"
            + "membergender   VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL);");    
    mystmtTwo = myConn.createStatement();
    mystmtTwo.execute("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 98111 WHERE name = 'mymembers';");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set `autoincrement` sequence on an empty-table you have to `insert` this value into `sqlite_sequence`, not `update`.

Consider this example ([jcabi-jdbc](https://jdbc.jcabi.com/) is used for handling queries):

```java
final JdbcSession session = new JdbcSession(src);
session
    .sql("CREATE TABLE members(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")
    .execute();
session
    .sql("INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence values(?,?)")
    .set("members")
    .set(123)
    .insert(Outcome.VOID);
session
    .sql("INSERT INTO members values(null)")
    .execute();
session
    .sql("INSERT INTO members values(null)")
    .execute();
final List<Integer> values = session
    .sql("SELECT id FROM members")
    .select(new ListOutcome<>(rset -> rset.getInt("id")));
MatcherAssert.assertThat(
    values,
    Matchers.equalTo(Arrays.asList(124, 125))
);
```